# My question is flagged as a possible duplicate

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement

I posted a question last night that I spent considerable time trying to fix myself. I couldn't do it, and so I put up a what I consider to be a well-described question with a clear title, what it is I wanted, what I had tried and a distinct question at the end.

Within a short time I had a comment that this is a possible duplicate of another question, and it is not. I say this because

- I want to insert specifically the text `\t` which is normally interpreted as a TAB
- I don't want to insert an actual TAB

Someone did come back and inform the first commenter that I in fact did NOT want to insert a TAB.

I originally left it at that.

I have come to revisit it today and assess the solutions provided and the question appeared as normal.

However just a moment ago, I've come in to update my question as requested and I'm getting a dialog reflecting that this question may in fact have an answer in the answer as first posted by the first commenter (who, if it's not clear, is wrong).

I usually go to great lengths to ensure my questions are clear even though my terminology may be wrong. I am a HUGE fan of Stack Exchange sites, and it alone has taught me a lot. I personally don't like it when questioners don't do the research on their own questions before posting, and I think that I give it a decent go when I myself ask.

My point now is that a user has obviously flagged the question as a possible duplicate without even having read the title or the question. My personal take is, if you don't have the time to read it, don't flag it. Again, your opinion might vary, but I think it's a solid argument.

But if I'm now getting this dialog, does that mean even though I believe my question is clear, concise, and precise in its wording, that I have to go in and edit it to explicitly say again that I don't want to insert a TAB?

Isn't the question clear enough as it is?

I realise I'm having a bit of a gripe here, and for that I apologise, I'm just tired of people flagging things as duplicates for what I consider to be brownie points or for reasons of self importance.

What should I be doing to avoid such murkiness in the future? And even in this question?

The question in question:

*[Incorrect escaping for regex expression in sed; I don't want a literal TAB, I want \t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503037/incorrect-escaping-for-regex-expr-in-sed-i-dont-want-a-literal-tab-i-want-t)*

The flagged possible answer:

*[What is the proper way to insert tab in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394066/what-is-the-proper-way-to-insert-tab-in-sed)*

Without even reading each question, I think it's obvious my question is exactly the opposite of the answer to the question that my question is a possible duplicate of.

*I hope by the last paragraph above that my sense of humour outweighs the ranty tones of the paragraphs before it.*

Comment: You should remove the answer that you edited in to your question body. Questions aren't meant to include the answer.

Comment: Is that true? I've always considered questions with how they arrived at the correct solution as always being that bit more informative. After all, the examples as in the answers given weren't exactly how I did it, although they were both technically correct. If anyone else up bites your comment then consider that edit gone :)

Comment: Actually now I'm just getting more and more confused. I thought the second answer also had the `-e` switch (which I still haven't researched).

Comment: Answers really don't belong in questions.  If you have an answer that is different from the other ones, then add an answer explaining how you solved it. If the other answers helped, but weren't quite right, you can credit them in your answer.

Comment: Rofl. That **is** funny. But in defense I was kind of asking how I could make it more clear, but I get your point. :D

Comment: *what I consider to be brownie points or for reasons of self importance* - It always amazes me how new users immediately jump to the conclusion that they are perfection and therefore everyone else here has malevolence in mind when they are critical. It couldn't possibly be just that the individual honestly believes that it's a duplicate, or made an honest mistake. No, of course not. It has to be **brownie points or self importance**, so that the newbie can assert their arrogance and feeling of superiority over those mortals who dare judge them.

Comment: And the irony: The question you wrote to complain about your question being closed as a duplicate is a **duplicate**, and was closed for that reason. No - clearly you could never make a mistake. You wrote the duplicate on purpose out of some evil intent; I don't know what it was, but it was **evil**. It has to be, because you *couldn't have made an **honest mistake**, right*?

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the laugh, and the input. I admit I was heated yesterday and it got to me that someone had misread the subject and didn't really bother to read the message, I just expect better. I could go on and give many examples of people feeling self important, but then I'd just be another newbie asserting my own arrogance. You know, I understand that thought process.

Comment: But for me, when I've spent hours on a problem, and usually an hour or more putting thought into wording my questions well, I expect more than someone clicking thru marking it as a duplicate in a heartbeat. Yes, people make honest mistakes. Even we're not perfect, are we Ken? (: Well, I am pretty damn close. FIGJAMITY :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

> What should I be doing to avoid such murkiness in future? and even in this question?

In this case, nothing really. The question is clearly not a duplicate of the suggested question. It currently has a single close vote, and it is unlikely to be closed in my view.

But incorrect close votes and flags happen all the time. That's why a question requires closevotes from 5 different people* in order for it to actually get closed.

As an aside, I am a bit concerned that all the examples in the question (and in the answers) modify a critical system file. What happens if somebody copy-pastes the example and runs it his home directory?

<sup>* or one person with gold tag badge</sup>

Comment: Does that mean the "possible duplicate" dialog remains? Re your aside, that is a good point and I will remove the actual filename from my question.

Comment: @Madivad The dialog is only visible to you. Nobody else sees it, unless it gets closed. I don't know if there is a way to dismiss it manually, but it goes away after a while.

Comment: Ahh right. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @Madivad the close vote will age away as well http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting

Comment: Can the "Possible duplicate" comment be flagged as 'obsolete'? I mean, obviously it can, but will a mod review it and decide it is *not*?